# I wish to install Skype and other downloaded programs on Linux, specifically Debian, AMD64 LXDE

Tags: linux, installation, skype, debian-squeeze

With Linux I have functioned up to now just using apt-get and modifying /etc/apt/sources.list . I followed the instructions in [this blog](http://www.debianadmin.com/install-skype-instant-messanger-in-debian-and-ubuntu.html). I added "`deb h ttp://download.skype.com/linux/repos/debian/ stable non-free`" to sources.list, then updated, then tried apt-get install skype

```
Package skype is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

This is probably what I get for using 5 year old blog found on google, but if you all share the right repository I can at least get skype to work. But this is part of a bigger problem I have.

I don't actually know how to install packages I download myself, rather than through apt. For instance, I got [official skype site's](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/) package downloaded, but I don't know how or where to unpack it, and if I have to do something to ensure my computer uses it. I also have a few other applications and games sitting on my hard drive untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the Skype official repos exist any more.

You would need to download it from Skype directly like you have, then use

```
dpkg -i skype-debian_2.2.0.35-1_i386.deb
```

(if you got the 32bit version).